# Flutter Newbie here. i dont know how to fix my database or my flutter. When I login a different account i can see others or information

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-test

[So my problem is that i can see other users info when i login from a different account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyYEV.png)

[Here is my firebase rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvns2.png)

I wish you could help me guys. im doing this for my school project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the rules you always give read access to other databases.

`allow read: if true;`

You have to do the same check below and it would be like this:

`alow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;`

[image]

Comment: you mean i should change this "allow read: if true;"  to this "alow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;"

Comment: Yes. You have to restrict the read access only to the logged-in user.

Comment: Try changing putting this snippet instead of yours:

`match /Users/{userId} {
     allow read, create, update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}`

Comment: you mean like this? https://ibb.co/2FK6M6F

Comment: wait ill try this

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function userDoc() {
      return /databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid);
    }

    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read: if true;
      match /Users/{userId} {allow read, create, update: if request.auth.uid == userId;}
    }

    // WARNING! ONLY FOR TEST MODE: Make sure you properly configure the
    // security rules for this collection before publishing your app.
    match /ToDoList/{id} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}

Comment: Check my edited answer. I added a picture of the required change.

Comment: The same change should be added to the code below the comment with the warning if the issue persists.

Comment: https://ibb.co/x56K5r3 it keeps on loading is my firebase correct